# How to calculate the Geometrical Extent/Etendue for an Optical Fiber?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

I would like to calculate the theoretical Geometrical Extent (G) for an optical fibre, however I am struggling a bit with the calculation of the needed solid angle based on the acceptance angle $\theta_{max}$

As far as I know Geometrical Extent is calculated by
$$
G_{OF} = A_{OF} \cdot \Omega_{OF}
$$

where A is the area of the optical fibre side, which is the area of the circle assuming a radius $r$ 
$$
A_{OF} = \pi \cdot r_{OF}^2
$$
and $\Omega_{OF}$ is the solid angle of the optical fibre.

Reaching this point, I make use of the expression for the NA to get my $\theta_{max}$ since it will impose the solid angle for the fibre:
$$
NA = n_o\cdot \sin(\theta_{max}) \to \theta_{max} = \arcsin(NA/n_o)
$$ 
Knowing that, I would like to obtaining the solid angle,$\Omega_{OF}$, given by the angle $\theta_{max}$. It will be defined by a cone due to our  $\theta_{max}$ angle , looking for the solid angle of a cone in literature is defined as 
$$
\Omega_{cone} = 2\cdot\pi\cdot(1-\cos(\theta))
$$
The acceptance angle $\theta_{max}$ only refers to half angle, but I need the whole angle to calculate the solid angle thus I have to multiply $\theta_{max}$ by two
$$
\Omega_{OF} = 2\cdot\pi\cdot(1-cos(2\cdot\theta_{max}) = 2\cdot\pi\cdot(1-\cos(2\cdot\arcsin(NA/n_o))
$$
and finally
 $$
G_{OF} = 2\cdot r_{OF}^2 \cdot\pi^2\cdot(1-cos(2\cdot\arcsin(NA/n_o))
$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: This looks sound, although in some fibers - particularly holey (photonic crystal fibers) with extremely high NA, the direction cosine of the field becomes significant and so you should calculate the grasp using the differential $n^2 \,\cos\theta \,\mathrm{d} A\,\mathrm{d}\Omega$ (you look like you're dropping the $\cos\theta$ term. You'll get a reasonable answer, but it's easy enough to include the exact definition.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I drop the $cos\theta$ because I am more interested on having the realtionship between the $G_{OF}$ and the NA, is that not appropiate?

Comment: It may well be perfectly OK as an approximation - it all depends on what you want to do with your calculation.  It would be interesting to see what would happen if you began with a more first principles definition of differential étendue rather than your first equation and carried out the integral.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance  do you mean starting from $dG = n^2*dS*cos(\theta)d\Omega$ and carrying the integral over the solid angle of the cone defined by the fiber NA?

Comment: Yes, you may also want to include any apodization factor in the integral, too, although the $\cos\theta$ is the main issue.

Comment: The solid angle is defined using the half-angle $\Omega =2\pi \left(1-\cos {\theta_{max} }\right)$, so you should not multiply it by two.  [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Cone,_spherical_cap,_hemisphere)

Comment: @svilches thanks, but I need the whole angle not just the half one

Comment: @ndarkness Could you please double check it? I think the following step is wrong: _"The acceptance angle θmax only refers to half angle, but I need the whole angle to calculate the solid angle thus I have to multiply θmax by two"_ . You don't need the whole angle in that equation, as described in my previous comment.

Comment: @svilches acceptance angle of a FO is defined as half angle since you're measuring it from the perpendicular to the FO, check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture#/media/File:Optic_fibre-numerical_aperture_diagram.svg and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guided_ray

Answer (score 0):

"The acceptance angle θmax only refers to half angle, but I need the whole angle to calculate the solid angle thus I have to multiply θmax by two".

This is wrong, the equation for the solid angle of the cone gives you the full solid angle, assuming theta is the half-angle of the cone (half of the full apex angle).

The correct solution is
GOF=2⋅r^2⋅π^2⋅(1−cos(arcsin(NA/no))